# Are final fields really useful regarding thread-safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, final

I have been working on a daily basis with the Java Memory Model for some years now. I think I have a good understanding about the concept of data races and the different ways to avoid them (e.g, synchronized blocks, volatile variables, etc). However, there's still something that I don't think I fully understand about the memory model, which is the way that final fields of classes are supposed to be thread safe without any further synchronization.

So according to the specification, if an object is properly initialized (that is, no reference to the object escapes in its constructor in such a way that the reference can be seen by another thread), then, after construction, any thread that sees the object will be guaranteed to see the references to all the final fields of the object (in the state they were when constructed), without any further synchronization.

In particular, the standard (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) says:

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields
>   for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a
>   reference to the object being constructed in a place where another
>   thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this
>   is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that
>   thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that
>   object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or
>   array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date
>   as the final fields are.

They even give the following example:

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

In which a thread A is supposed to run "reader()", and a thread B is supposed to run "writer()".

So far, so good, apparently.

My main concern has to do with... is this really useful in practice? As far as I know, in order to make thread A (which is running "reader()") see the reference to "f", we must use some synchronization mechanism, such as making f volatile, or using locks to synchronize access to f. If we don't do so, we are not even guaranteed that "reader()" will be able to see an initialized "f", that is, since we have not synchronized access to "f", the reader will potentially see "null" instead of the object that was constructed by the writer thread. This issue is stated in http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#finalWrong , which is one of the main references for the Java Memory Model [bold emphasis mine]:

> Now, having said all of this, if, after a thread constructs an
>   immutable object (that is, an object that only contains final fields),
>   you want to ensure that it is seen correctly by all of the other
>   thread, you still typically need to use synchronization. **There is no
>   other way to ensure, for example, that the reference to the immutable
>   object will be seen by the second thread**. The guarantees the program
>   gets from final fields should be carefully tempered with a deep and
>   careful understanding of how concurrency is managed in your code.

So if we are not even guaranteed to see the reference to "f", and we must therefore use typical synchronization mechanisms (volatile, locks, etc.), and these mechanisms do already cause data races to go away, the need for final is something I would not even consider. I mean, if in order to make "f" visible to other threads we still need to use volatile or synchronized blocks, and they already make internal fields be visible to the other threads... what's the point (in thread safety terms) in making a field final in the first place?

Comment: " and they already make internal fields be visible to the other threads" this is only true if those internal fields are final.

Answer (score 11):

I think that you are misunderstanding what the JLS example is intended to show:

```
static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
        int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
        int j = f.y;  // could see 0
    } 
}
```

This code does not guarantee that the latest value of `f` will be seen by the thread that calls `reader()`.  But what it is saying is that if you do see `f` as non-null, then `f.x` is guaranteed to be `3` ... despite the fact that we didn't actually do any explicit synchronizing.

Well is this implicit synchronization for finals in constructors useful?  Certainly it is ... IMO.  It means that we don't *need* to do any extra synchronization each time we accessed an immutable object's state.  That is a good thing, because synchronization typically entails cache read-through or write-through, and that slows your program down.

But what Pugh is saying is that you will *typically* need to synchronize to *get hold of* the reference to the immutable object in the first place. He is making the point that using immutable objects (implemented using `final`) does not excuse you from the need to synchronize ... or from the need to understand the concurrency / synchronization implementation of your application.

---

> The problem is that we still need to be sure that reader will se a non-null "f", and that's only possible if we use other synchronization mechanism that will already provide the semantics of allowing us to see 3 for f.x. And if that's the case, why bother using final for thread safety stuff?

There is a difference between synchronizing to get the reference and synchronizing to use the reference.  The first one I may need to do only once.  The second one I may need to do lots of times ... with the same reference.  And even if it is one-to-one, I have still halved the number of synchronizing operations ... if I (hypothetically) implement the immutable object as thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer. Well, my main point is that even though you are guaranteed to see 3 for f.x "iff you do see f as non-null", the problem is that we still need to be sure that reader will se a non-null "f", and that's only possible if we use other synchronization mechanism that will already provide the semantics of  allowing us to see 3 for f.x. And if that's the case, why bother using final for thread safety stuff?

Comment: @KnucklestheEchidna Suppose you have a cache, and you don't care if some thread sees a stale value for some time. What you care about is that it should see correct values (stale or not). Unsafely publishing the cached object will work fine if its fields are final. It won't if its fields are not final: a thread might see some new values and some old ones.

Comment: @JBNizet well, but in the end we want to make sure that the reader thread sees the cache in a non-stale state. Otherwise the reader may not even have access to the objects of the cache, ever. And if that's the case, the mechanism to make the reader see a non-stale cache will also cause a memory synchronization event that will make final fields not very useful, IMO, right?

Comment: @StephenC easy, sir, I am just trying to learn here ; ). I'd still like to get some clarification in the cache example, anyway.

Comment: @KnucklestheEchidna - Ask JB Nizet.  It is his example.

Comment: @StephenC regarding your last edit, yes, I see that there are two different things here, publishing the reference and using the reference. However, I think my point still remains: if publishing the reference also forces a happens-before relation, then using final fields does not seem to have any effect here, right?

Comment: Another reason I can think of for the rule is that it guarantees that (excluding initialization cycles) you'll never see the value of a final field change throughout its lifetime - seems like that should simplify life for static analyzers and in similar situations but is something that most programmers will expect and not question.

Comment: @KnucklestheEchidna - Maybe you are right.  Maybe the number of real-world use-cases where you wouldn't also need to synchronize anyway is ... tiny.  (Maybe the special `final` semantics are little more than a solution for the double-check locking problem ...).  But like I said, it is moot.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** Most software developers should ignore the special rules regarding *final* variables in the *Java Memory Model*. They should adhere to the general rule: If a program is free of *data races*, all executions will appear to be *sequentially consistent*. In most cases, *final* variables can not be used to improve the performance of concurrent code, because the special rule in the *Java Memory Model* creates some additional costs for *final* variables, what makes *volatile* superior to *final* variables for almost all use cases.

The special rule about *final* variables prevents in some cases, that a *final* variable can show different values. However, performance-wise the rule is irrelevant.

---

Having said that, here is a more detailed answer. But I have to warn you. The following description might contain some precarious information, that most software developers should never care about, and it's better if they don't know about it.

The special rule about *final* variables in the *Java Memory Model* somehow implies, that it makes a difference for the Java VM and Java JIT compiler, if a member variable is *final* or if it's not.

```
public class Int {
    public /* final */ int value;
    public Int(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the *Hotspot* source code, you will see that the compiler checks if the constructor of a class writes at least one *final* variable. If it does so, the compiler will emit additional code for the constructor, more precisely a *memory release barrier*. You will also find the following comment in the source code:

> This method (which must be a constructor by the rules of Java)
>   wrote a final.  The effects of all initializations must be
>   committed to memory before any code after the constructor
>   publishes the reference to the newly constructor object.
>   Rather than wait for the publication, we simply block the
>   writes here.  Rather than put a barrier on only those writes
>   which are required to complete, we force all writes to complete.

That means the initialization of a *final* variable is similar to a write of a *volatile* variable. It implies some kind of *memory release barrier*. However, as can be seen from the quoted comment, *final* variables might be even more expensive. And what's even worse, you have these additional costs for *final* variables regardless whether they are used in concurrent code or not.

That's awful, because we want software developers to use *final* variables in order to increase the *readability* and *maintainability* of source code. Unfortunately, using *final* variables can significantly impact the performance of a program.

---

The question remains: Are there any use cases where the special rule regarding *final* variables helps to improve the performance of *concurrent* code?

That's hard to tell, because it depends on the actual implementation of the Java VM and the memory architecture of the machine. I haven't seen any such use cases until now. A quick glance at the source code of the package *java.util.concurrent* has also revealed nothing.

The problem is: The initialization of a *final* variable is about as expensive as a write of a *volatile* or *atomic* variable. If you use a *volatile* variable for the reference of the newly created object, you get the same behaviour and costs with the exception, that the reference will also be *published* immediately. So, there is basically no benefit in using *final* variables for concurrent programming.

Comment: If you're really worried about the cost of a StoreLoad memory barrier, you're either writing extremely high-performance code where you allocate millions of such objects or you're microoptimizing. "Apparently, final variables are way to expensive compared to volatile variables and atomic data types" - huh? Volatiles (which is what atomic data types use internally anyhow) need the same barriers after every single write! Any benchmarks/programs where the addition of "final" really "significantly" impacts performance?

Comment: @Voo: You are putting words into my mouth. The point is, _final_ is at least as expensive as _volatile_. That means there is no benefit in using _final_ for thread-safety, because you can achieve more with _volatile_.

Comment: I assume English isn't your first language, but if "X is way too expensive compared to Y" this does imply that X is more expensive than Y. Yes I agree that the rules for final help only in very few situations, but I disagree that the cost of a single StoreLoad barrier is prohibitively expensive or should stop anybody from using the final modifier! If you benchmark the code and can really show a significant performance impact of the barrier, sure remove it - but I can't imagine a single non-contrived example where this would be the case.

Comment: Anyhow the reason for the final rule seems clear to me: It avoids the possibility of someone seeing a final field change its value through its lifetime (still a problem with initialization cycles, but those are deterministic at least) - Java generally tends to go for added safety/clarity over small performance benefits. For the same reason it guarantees that you'll never see the uninitialized value of a field even in the case of race conditions (you may see the initial 0, but not some garbage) despite this also having costs.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. OP asked about visibility and you talked about performance. You also say that final is at least as expensive as volatile because final variables incur some kind of barrier once per constructor invocation, but volatile variables incur that cost on every access, even on a single thread. Moreover, most often one wants a variable to be final because it's going to be constant, in which case you can't declare it volatile at all, so your conclusion that final variables have no benefit in concurrent programming doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Boann: The question refers to section [§17.5.1 Semantics of final Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1) of the JLS, not about [§4.12.4 final Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) in general. C++ has also _const_ variables, but there is nothing like §17.5.1 in C++. So, the question was: Is §17.5.1 of any help. I argued against it. If you don't agree, can you provide an example that shows the actual use of §17.5.1?

Comment: @nosid Yes, the question was about semantics, not flawed speculation about performance. And you've totally missed my other point: you **can't** declare a final (i.e., constant) variable volatile, so saying that final's threading behavior is useless because you could just use volatile instead is wrong.

Comment: @Boann: Did you really read the question, my answer and §17.5.1? We are talking about the impact of _final_ member variables of a class _C_ on the assignments of references for newly created _C_ objects to _non-final_ variables. Of course, the latter **can** be _volatile_ or _atomic_. Also, the OP apparently understands the semantics of §17.5.1. He wanted to know if there is a real benefit of §17.5.1.

Comment: @nosid Yes there is a benefit: visibility to other threads of final field values set during a constructor. Did *you* really read §17.5.1?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, since locking makes stronger guarantees, the guarantee about availability of `final`s is not particularly useful in the presence of locking. However, locking is not always necessary to ensure reliable concurrent access.

> As far as I know, in order to make thread A (which is running "reader()") see the reference to "f", we must use some synchronization mechanism, such as making f volatile, or using locks to synchronize access to f.

Making `f` volatile is not a synchronization mechanism; it forces threads to read the memory each time the variable is accessed, but it does not synchronize access to a memory location. Locking is a way to synchronize access, but it is not necessary in practice to guarantee that the two threads share data reliably. For example, you could use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>` class, which is a lock-free concurrent collection<sup>*</sup> , to pass data from a reader thread to a writer thread, and avoid synchronization. You could also use [`AtomicReference<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) to ensure reliable concurrent access to an object without locking.

It is when you use [lock-free concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) that the guarantee about the visibility of `final` fields come in handy. If you make a lock-free collection, and use it to store immutable objects, your threads would be able to access the content of the objects without additional locking.

<sup>*</sup>  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>` is not only lock-free, but also a wait-free collection (i.e. a lock-free collection with additional guarantees not relevant to this discussion).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you say that _AtomicReference_ is a synchronization mechanism, whereas _volatile_ is none?! That sounds weird.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for the quick response. By "volatile being a synchronization mechanism" I actually meant regarding memory visibility, sorry for the confusion. The ConcurrentLinkedQueue class actually has some memory consistency guarantees (as usual in concurrent collections), so I don't see why final fields would make a difference here : L

Comment: @nosid I wasn't precise about the atomic reference - I shouldn't say "synchronization", thanks for the correction.

Comment: @KnucklestheEchidna `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is lock-free, so it's in the same boat as your `f` variable in terms of access guarantees of *other* objects. Making access to `f` synchronized would force JVM to "flush" the content of CPU cache into memory, which would guarantee that both final and non-final variables are available. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does not have such a "shotgun" mechanism in its implementation that could influence *your* object along with the queue's objects, so the guarantee about `final`s becomes important.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry, I don't think I follow. ConcurrentLinkedQueue provides happens-before semantics in the add()/remove() family of methods, so placing and then retrieving an object from the queue is going to "flush" the whole content of the object, whether its fields are final or not, right?

Comment: This answer is not correct. If you publish an object via any safe publication idiom (according to _Java Concurrency In Practice_), you will never see a partially constructed object. `final` does not add value for `AtomicReference` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (uses `volatile`). Safe publication idioms:

1 Initializing an object reference from a static initializer;
2 Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or AtomicReference;
3 Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed object; or
4 Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a lock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes final final fields are useful in terms of thread-safety. It may not be useful in your example, however if you look at the  old `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation the get method doesn't apply any locking while it search for the value, though there is a risk that while look up is happening the list might change (think of ConcurrentModificationException ). However CHM uses the list made of final filed for 'next' field guaranteeing the consistency of the list (the items in the front/yet-to see will not grow or shrink). So the advantage is thread-safety is established without synchronization.

From the article

> Exploiting immutability
>
> One significant source of inconsistency is avoided by making the Entry
>   elements nearly immutable -- all fields are final, except for the
>   value field, which is volatile. This means that elements cannot be
>   added to or removed from the middle or end of the hash chain --
>   elements can only be added at the beginning, and removal involves
>   cloning all or part of the chain and updating the list head pointer.
>   So once you have a reference into a hash chain, while you may not know
>   whether you have a reference to the head of the list, you do know that
>   the rest of the list will not change its structure. Also, since the
>   value field is volatile, you will be able to see updates to the value
>   field immediately, greatly simplifying the process of writing a Map
>   implementation that can deal with a potentially stale view of memory.
>
> While the new JMM provides initialization safety for final variables,
>   the old JMM does not, which means that it is possible for another
>   thread to see the default value for a final field, rather than the
>   value placed there by the object's constructor. The implementation
>   must be prepared to detect this as well, which it does by ensuring
>   that the default value for each field of Entry is not a valid value.
>   The list is constructed such that if any of the Entry fields appear to
>   have their default value (zero or null), the search will fail,
>   prompting the get() implementation to synchronize and traverse the
>   chain again.

Article link: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp08223/

Comment: But if I undestood it correctly, all of that applies to the old JMM, where "final" did not have any thread-safe semantics (actually the article states that), so it does not apply here

Comment: If I my understanding is not wrong, The article says on Old JVM, the final field's guarantee of initialization safety is not strong, so the code checks for default value. However on new JVMs thats not needed, and final fields are guaranteed to be fully initialized. On new jvms final fields save the client code from using locks when iterating the final backed list.